# Animate append to list

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, jquery-animate

How could I animate the moving from one list to another, ideally using Jquery animate? Given the following code I know I should be able to use animate to move the listitem to the position it would take up in the receiving list... but how do I get the coordinates, and translate them into css values?

```js
$('#list1').on('click', 'li', function() {
 // $(this).animate( ??? )
 $(this).appendTo($('#list2'));
})

$('#list2').on('click', 'li', function() {
 // $(this).animate( ??? )
 $(this).appendTo($('#list1'));
})
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: grey;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
  <li>four</li>
  <li>five</li>
  <li>six</li>
</ul>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpjsh2h6/1/)

Comment: Can you explain what output you want from the css?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's Saturday evening (local-time) and I want to help someone, I took your question seriously and provided an example along with explanations at each step below.

The most important thing in this example is to use an absolute positioned list-element (in this example `#animatedList`) so that this animated list-element does not interact with other elements. Furthermore getting the correct coordinates you have to take margins/paddings of the original elements into consideration as well.

You have to click on the Button "Run code snippet" to execute this example. Hope this helps you:

```js
$('#list1').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var startElement = $(this);
  var endElement = $('#list2');
  startAnimation(startElement, endElement);
})

$('#list2').on('click', 'li', function() {
  var startElement = $(this);
  var endElement = $('#list1');
  startAnimation(startElement, endElement);
})

function startAnimation(startElement, endElement){
  var clickedListElement = startElement;
  // copy content of original element into animated list-element 
  var contentCopy = clickedListElement.text();
  var startCoords = getCoordsOfElement(clickedListElement);
  // if there are no li-elements anymore take the position of the whole list instead otherwise take last list-element
  var endCoords;
  if(endElement.find('li:last').length)endCoords = getCoordsOfElement(endElement.find('li:last'));
  else endCoords = getCoordsOfElement(endElement);
  // hide original element because the animated list-element will be shown 
  clickedListElement.css('visibility','hidden');
  showAnimation(contentCopy,startCoords,endCoords,function(){
   // the last step: copy the original element to it's destination and show it again because the animation is over
   clickedListElement.appendTo(endElement).css('visibility','visible');
  });
}

function getCoordsOfElement(element){
  var endCoords = element.offset();
  // because the margin and paddings of these lists distorts the calculated position you have to take them into consideration
  // and therefore we subtract them for top and left
  var marginOffsetTop = 50;
  endCoords.top -= marginOffsetTop;
  var marginOffsetLeft = 50;
  endCoords.left -= marginOffsetLeft;
  // the same happens with padding 
  var paddingOffsetTop = 10;
  endCoords.top -= paddingOffsetTop;
  var paddingOffsetLeft = 10;
  endCoords.left -= paddingOffsetLeft;
  return endCoords;
}

function showAnimation(contentCopy,startCoord,endCoord,callback){
 var list = $('#animatedList');
 // copy text of originel element into animated-list-element
 list.find('li').text(contentCopy);
 // set animated-list/element at the same position as the original clicked element
 list.css('top',startCoord.top+'px').css('left',startCoord.left+'px').show();
 list.animate({
   top: endCoord.top+'px',
   left: endCoord.left+'px'
 }, 1000, function(){
    // animation is finished here
    list.hide();
    callback();
 });
}
```

```css
ul {
  background-color: grey;
  color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 50px;
  width: 20%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#animatedList{
  display:none;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="list1">
<li>one</li>
<li>two</li>
<li>three</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list2">
<li>four</li>
<li>five</li>
<li>six</li>
</ul>

<ul id="animatedList">
<li></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please, give me a feedback about whether this fulfills your request. Thank you.

Comment: That is awesome! Thank you! Works a treat.. the only thing is that I lose the styles (in my code at least, seems to keep them here) whilst the animation is occuring. Maybe something I'm missing on the css, but it could be because it is responding to socket.io 'move' events to call the animation, and the fact that my LIs are quite complex with many divs and styles in them perhaps?

Comment: You are welcome! Yes, when the list‘s are more complex than in this example, then you have to extend or modify the style of #animatedList according to your requirements, but I‘m sure you get over this. It would be great when you mark my answer as right to make it officially, please. It has been a pleasure:)

Comment: Have accepted the answer! Will the fact that the code copies the .text element affect the styling... I mean, does .text capture all children or does it break it up and remove them?

Comment: Thanks! .text only copies "text" of a list-element or it's children, but no elements themselves. You can also use .html instead to copy not only text but all children as well.